# Get DOM element's name as <li> instead of [object HTMLLIElement]

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I'm fetching `<li>` element like:

```
document.getElementById('cities-drop').children[0].toString()
```

result is: `[object HTMLLIElement]`

Is it possible with pure JS get result as:

```
li
```

or

```
<li>
```

without overriding `toString()` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var el = documnet.getElementById('cities-drop').children[0];
console.log(el.tagName); // li
```

I believe you're looking for [`.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName).

Comment: yeah,looks like the link is broken

Comment: @nfechner: I can [search for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=tagName) fine, but for some reason MDN killed that reference. I'm thinking they're in the middle of an overhaul and should be back up. Either way, `tagName` is the answer, and resources can be found elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: yes,that's ok.I just assume to add `.toLowerCase` invokation also